# how set domain dns for my local server with public static ip

Tags: windows, dns, ip

i have adsl modem with static ip for example (2.180.180.4), i set port forwarding dsl modem to my local server with 192.168.1.1, with port 80. it mean i can access to my web page hosted on iis with requesting blow address to browser

```
 http://2.180.180.4:80
```

now i have domain like abc.com, i want to set dns (domain name sever) of domain what i must set on dns? 
i have windows server 12 on my server what i must do on it to windows handle my request with my domain name?

Comment: You should define a new a record in your registar and define host bindings in iis.

Comment: can you explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first think u need nameserver ex: ns1.domain.com ( you can set it in your domain registrar company  )
second dns manager on your windows 2012 , setup dns service and set your ns1.domain.com on your local IP 192.168.1.103 .
next add A record to * and Empty and www to localIP 192.168.1.103 , now dns is oky

next go to iis and add bind domain.com to your website under your iis

don't forget add portforwarding 53 in your modem adsl to your localip port 53.

all is done and enjoy your home host company

Answer (score 1):

Sure so let's start with the IIS:
Right click This PC (Previously my Computer) and choose manage. Go to Services and Applications => Internet information Services => Sites, Right click on the site and click Bindings => Add your Hostname for port 80.
Now the Registar:
Go to your register or your DNS management service: Go Daddy, Namecheap, Amazon Route53 etc'.
And add a new a record - Choose the domain and add the Static IP Value - This might take about 24 to be applied in the entire world but usually it happens within a few hours depending on your service provider.

Comment: on dns manager i cannot see any item that you tell me "Go Daddy, Namecheap, Amazon Route53 etc" i must configure dns server, or create new zone or other things??

Comment: A new DNS entry "A Record" if you have a static IP - What's your DNS provider? I might be able to help in where.

Comment: i have only internet provider with static ip, do you mean i must have dns provider? what is it? sorry i am very new in network and configuring server...

Comment: You said you purchased a domain - Where is the domain managed?

Comment: oh ok yes i purchased a domain, in my domain setting i can set 4 ns record.. what i must set in records?

Comment: the 4 DNS records are for a DNS management service like route53 in Amazon or if you would like you can use cloudflare which is free and also gives you CDN services, after you sign up look for instruction on what IPs to put in you registar account and then you can manage the DNS records there - add as many records as you want and point them to any IP you would like.